# Expo stuck on endless loading screen when trying to start app on real phone

Tags: android, react-native, expo, node-modules

I recently set up a new react native project, which I test on my phone using expo.

It worked fine in the beginning, I could start the app on my phone without problems using the QR code from expo. However after some time it stopped working, when I now try to load the app on my phone with the qr code expo it stuck on an endless loading screen. I don't get any error messages and the app loads perfectly fine when I start it inside the browser, again without any error messages.

I tried to delete the node_modules folder and reinstall it with yarn and npm, like it was recommended, but it still doesn't work.

I think it started after I installed some package, but even after I removed it it still didn't work:

my installed packages (from package-lock.json and package.json (the packages are exactly the same) ):

```
    "@react-navigation/native": "^3.8.4",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~10.2.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.8.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.14.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
```

I also removed the routing from App.js and replaced it with some basic code, but it still doesn't work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const YourApp = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>
        Try editing me! 
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default YourApp;
```

Comment: just the delete the expo app and reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I was using rem size units which are not supported in react native. However, this should not happen with your replaced basic code.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was a network problem I had to reset the router.